# How to check collision in a drawn curve, instead of the Sprite's bound box

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, math

There are two Sprite's hit tests, one check the object (and have no precision on the curves) and the other check a specified (x, y) point. But, having curves drawn using `Graphics.curveTo()`, how do I check if 2 drawn curves are colliding?

I'm not sure if this is an actionscript or a math problem... I want to check all (x,y) of a curve to all (x,y) of the other curve..

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bezier curve intersections are a little tricky to calculate, but take a look at [ActionSnippet - Bezier Intersections (not a snippet), By Zevan](http://actionsnippet.com/?p=965). There are some useful functions, and a working example just under the code.

A better way to do collision detection (in my opinion) would be the method described here: [Skinner collision detection in AS3](http://labs.boulevart.be/index.php/2007/06/08/skinner-collision-detection-in-as3/). A full collision detection library has been made here that seems to work really well: [Collision Detection Kit (AS3)](http://www.coreyoneil.com/portfolio/index.php?project=5).

Comment: Cool.. I was reading about the Bezier before, but the already done Collision Detection Kit seems perfect.. :)